# solution of $\Delta f = 0 $ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

It is asserted that the only solution is $f = 0 $. How to prove it?

I am actually quite confused as many functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are non-differentiable neither in the strong nor in the weak sense, so $\Delta  f $ might not make sense for $f$.

Comment: It says that if $f$ satisfies $\Delta f=0$ **and** $f \in L^{2}$ then $f=0$. Use Mean Value Property over large balls.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99030/a-property-of-weakly-harmonic-functions